# iOS8 UIButton title disappear

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, ios8

I have a button in my app that is perfectly visible on iOS7. But when I switch to iOS8 the title label for this button does not appear. And I can see only border around the button.
Here is the code that makes the button. Could someone give me a clue where the problem is?

```
UIButton *problem = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[problem addTarget:self action:@selector(problemButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
problem.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[problem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ReportAProblem", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
problem.titleLabel.textColor = CUSTOM_DARK_GRAY_COLOR;
[[problem layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[[problem layer] setBorderColor:CUSTOM_DARK_GRAY_COLOR.CGColor];
problem.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
problem.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I found an answer for this question but immediately there is another:
I encounter the very same problem with some of my UILabels, for example:

```
 self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
self.label.numberOfLines = 1;
self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.label.textColor = self.textColor;
CGFloat fontSize = self.bounds.size.height / 5;
self.label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
```

Comment: well it seems that i suddenly found an answer myself. I simply had to add `[problem setTitleColor:CUSTOM_DARK_GRAY_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal];` to my code

Comment: Why are you trying to set a ratio of your view height as a font size ? Maybe doing it with your label makes more sense. `CGFloat fontSize = self.label.bounds.size.height / 5;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state` instead of `titleLabel.textColor`.

Second problem: Why are you trying to set a ratio of your view height as a font size ? Maybe doing it with your label makes more sense. `CGFloat fontSize = self.label.bounds.size.height / 5;` Anyway what you usually want to do is have a fixed font size and adapt the label frame around it.

Comment: Well thank you for the answer @Starscream. Can you give an answer for the second part of my question?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. And that hack with the fontSize - that was needed. And it doesn't make a problem.

Comment: Well i found that the problem was not in the label itself, but in my CLLocationManager as it was the source of the data for the label. ` locationManager: didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation:` is now deprecated and  we should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations: ` instead. So i think you did answer my question. But the question was not right.